# Using JS to show/hide posts in a feed based on checkboxes, how do I filter duplicate posts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

After two days of trying I cannot figure out how to display unique posts. I'm open to either PHP/Laravel or JavaScript solutions.

There is a feed that displays posts based on their category. Posts can have more than one category. Checkboxes determine which posts to show.

This is my view. The first ul is two checkboxes which represent post categories - foo and bar. The second ul is iterating over a Collection of posts and creates an li for each post, which contains the post category (either foo or bar) and the post title. The class of the div for each post is the name of the category.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="foo" type="checkbox" id="foo" name="checkbox" value="foo">
    <label for="foo">foo</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="bar" type="checkbox" id="bar" name="checkbox" value="bar">
    <label for="bar">bar</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
    <div class="{{ $post->category }}">
      <li>
        <p>{{ $post->title }}</p>
        <p>{{ $post->category }}</p>
      </li>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This is the JS. It hides the divs of unchecked boxes and shows those of checked boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    });
});
```

This is the Laravel Query Builder code, it joins the category and posts tables. The category table contains one entry for each post + category combination. The post table contains one entry for each post. So a post with two categories shows up once in the post table, twice in the categories table.

```
$posts = Post::join('categories', 'post.id', '=', 'categories.post_id')
                            ->select('title', 'category')
                            ->distinct()
                            ->get();
```

With one post in the collection and that post having categories foo and bar, this is the result:

```
<div>
  <li>post title</li>
  <li>foo</li>
</div>
<div>
  <li>post title</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</div>
```

The post is getting returned twice. I'd like it only to be returned once.

Comment: What is Post-Category relationships? And you must show your sql query? Is resulted data shown as duplicated?

You can look **posts** data in your controller how return only **$posts** variable, count($posts) or var_dump($posts).

I think your relationship or your query is wrong. You only have unique posts with multiple categories.

Comment: You are right, I needed to add the query as the fact that I'm joining tables (category and posts) is a factor here. I have just added that. Thank you.

Comment: You must use groupBy post.id on your query and concat category names. 

`
$posts = Post::join('categories', 'post.id', '=', 'categories.post_id')
                            ->selectRaw('title, concat_ws(',',category)')
                            ->groupBy('post.id')
                            ->get();
`

You can think Eloquent way for better understanding: Relationships, Eager loading and whereHas query.